# Pass functional arguments through ternary operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, conditional-operator

This might be a basic question because I am still learning Python. But let's suppose I want to do something like this,

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
sum = add(a, b if b == 2 else c, d)
```

Basically, I am trying to pass multiple functional args from inside a ternary operator(and I want a similar solution, if possible). This code currently gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**What else have I tried:**

- `add((a, b) if b == 2 else (c, d))`
- `add(*(a, b) if b == 2 else *(c, d))`

Comment: When the parentheses get confusing, it's a sign that you shouldn't be cramming it onto one line in the first place - harms readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```py
add(*(a, b) if b == 9 else (c, d))
```

It is similar to

```py
add(*((a, b) if b == 9 else (c, d)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> add(*((a, b) if b == 2 else (c, d)))
3
```

As pointed out in the comments, the fact that you need so many parens to do this is a good sign that this is not a good way to structure this code.

Answer (score 1):

`sum_ = add(a, b) if b==2 else add(c, d)`

above statement is equivalent to

```
sum_ = 0
if b==2:
    sum_ = add(a, b)
else:
    sum_ = add(c, d)
```

if in confusion, it is better to write a full statement, and then try to make it simple and in Turney.

Also, it's recommended, not to use the inbuilt function for the variable name

Comment: Is it possible to call the function just once and pass the args through ternary operator, because it is possible in case of a single argument?

Comment: @zean_7 as already given solution by other, you just need to select the 2 values which fill the condition and pass those value to functions as `sum_ = add(*((a,b) if b==2 else (c,d)))`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the fucntion argument ,you declare a fucntion with 2 variable but you pass 3 ,what i inderstand you pass argument to funciton and it return the sum of the argument ,you can do this

```
def add(*args):
   return sum(args)
a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
value = add(a, b if b == 2 else c, d)
```

*don't declare sum as variable it is an an inbuilt function of python *